# move folder from mounted cifs to ntfs take ages

Tags: cifs, copy, mv

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 and have a network drive mounted via cifs.

When I try to copy a dir from that network drive the copying took ages (ubuntu says 596.523 hours).
Neither mv (shell) nor copy (mouse) works.
The dir containing 30 GB of files. The Connection is via Ethernet.

On every read I perform on the network drive Journalctl says:

gvfsd-metadata[6525]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed

Copying single files works perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: My first question would have been "What do you consider ages..." but man that's is a long estimated time.... Have you considered the contents of the directory? Are they all giant files? Have you considered your internet connection? Are you able to connect via ethernet and try that way?

Comment: How big is the directory?

Comment: What's in the logs? `journalctl` and search for the times you did copying. BTW, `mv` only "works" if SOURCE and DESTINATION are on the same volume. That's not the case here, so `mv` changes to `cp`. See `info '(coreutils) mv invocation'`

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm copying 690mb of files, 692 files, and it's giving me an estimate of 24 hours to copy them all. It's a virtual machine running on the same exact computer I'm copying from. There should be no latency whatsoever.